# Draw PNG on Canvas using pixels; formula?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, java-2d

I'm following a couple of Java2D tutorials, and am now trying to draw a simple PNG on a Canvas.

I create a `BufferedImage` and then retrieve the pixel data with `pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();`.

Then, I load my PNG in a similar fashion:

```
spriteImage = ImageIO.read(Shape.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
width = spriteImage .getWidth();
height = spriteImage .getHeight();
spritePixels = spriteImage .getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
```

However, I now have to write the contents from `spritePixels` into `pixels`, and am stumped on the formula:

Assuming the height and width of `spriteImage` will always be less than `image`, and that I'll always be drawing into position 0,0 I believe my formula will look something like this:

```
for (int spriteIndex = 0; spriteIndex < spritePixels.length; spriteIndex ++)
  pixels[spriteIndex + offset] = spritePixels[x];
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the offset.  What's the formula, here?

Comment: Do you need an offset if you draw in the upperleft corner?

Comment: "Offset" is probably not the right word.  It's the value that gets added to the index so that the smaller sprite is inserted over the same mask in the larger drawing area.  

A 4x4 sprite on a 20x6 would look like this:
0->0, 1->1, 2->2, 3->3, 4->20, 5->21.  I'm trying to figure out the formula to do this translation.

Comment: What kind of canvas is this? If you just want to paint an image on top of another, you don't need to go to the pixel level, just use one of the Graphics.drawImage methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to map the index to its row/column in the smaller image then find out what row/column it corresponds to in the other image. This should work:

```
public class OffsetCalc {
private int rows;
private int cols;
private int rowsOther;
private int colsOther;

public OffsetCalc(int rows, int cols, int rowsOther, int colsOther) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.rowsOther = rowsOther;
    this.colsOther = colsOther;
}

public void getOffset(int i) {
    int col = i % cols;
    int row = i / cols;
    System.out.println("i=" + i + " @row,col: " + row + "," + col);

    int other = (col) + (row * rowsOther);
    System.out.println("i=" + i + " @Other image: " + other);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OffsetCalc calc = new OffsetCalc(4, 4, 20, 6);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        calc.getOffset(i);
    }
}
}
```

Outputs:

```
i=0 @row,col: 0,0
i=0 @Other image: 0
i=1 @row,col: 0,1
i=1 @Other image: 1
i=2 @row,col: 0,2
i=2 @Other image: 2
i=3 @row,col: 0,3
i=3 @Other image: 3
i=4 @row,col: 1,0
i=4 @Other image: 20
i=5 @row,col: 1,1
i=5 @Other image: 21
i=6 @row,col: 1,2
i=6 @Other image: 22
i=7 @row,col: 1,3
i=7 @Other image: 23
i=8 @row,col: 2,0
i=8 @Other image: 40
i=9 @row,col: 2,1
i=9 @Other image: 41
i=10 @row,col: 2,2
i=10 @Other image: 42
i=11 @row,col: 2,3
i=11 @Other image: 43
i=12 @row,col: 3,0
i=12 @Other image: 60
i=13 @row,col: 3,1
i=13 @Other image: 61
i=14 @row,col: 3,2
i=14 @Other image: 62
```